# call to reverseString.reverseStr errored : VM exception while processing transaction Invalid opcode

Tags: solidity

I am writing simple program to reverse string using solidity ,everything looks ok but while executing the program am getting the error

"**call to reverseString.reverseStr errored : VM exception while processing transaction Invalid opcode"**

contract reverseString{

```
string a;

function setA(string memory x)public{
    a = x;
}

function reverseStr() public view returns(string memory){
    bytes memory entString = bytes(a);

    string memory revStrings =new  string(entString.length);

    bytes memory revString = bytes(revStrings);

    uint k=0;
    require(revString.length>0);

    for(uint i=revString.length;i>0 ;i--){
       revString[k++] = entString[i];
   }

    return string(revString);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The first time through your loop, `i` is `revString.length`, which is also the length of `entString`. So `entString[i]` is trying to read one element past the end of the array.

I haven't checked for other issues, but that first issue should be fixed with:

```
for (uint i = revString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

**EDIT**

The above code will produce an infinite loop, because `i >= 0` is always true, given that `i` is unsigned. You could switch to using a signed variable or count down from `revString.length` to `> 0` and use `i - 1` as your index, but it's probably simpler to just write the loop in the more straightforward way (forward):

```
for (uint256 i = 0; i < revString.length; i++) {
    revString[i] = entString[revString.length - i - 1];
}
```

Simplifying the whole function to use fewer variables:

```
bytes memory b = bytes(a);
bytes memory ret = new bytes(b.length);

for (uint256 i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    ret[i] = b[b.length - i - 1];
}

return string(ret);
```

Comment: I tried the same but still getting the same error :                                               
 function reverseStr() public view returns(string memory){
        bytes memory entString = bytes(a);
        
        string memory revStrings =new  string(entString.length);
       
        bytes memory revString = bytes(revStrings);
       
        uint k=0;
        require(revString.length>0);
        
        for(uint i=revString.length-1;i>=0 ;i--){
           revString[k++] = entString[i];
       }
        
        return string(revString);
    }

Comment: Ah, the remaining issue is because `uint`s, being unsigned, are _always_ greater than or equal to zero. The `i--` is underflowing the integer, so you have an infinite loop. There are a few fixes... I'll edit my answer now with a couple.

Comment: any further update on it

Comment: Are you still having some sort of trouble? If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

=> `myContract.reverseStrMain()` will return reversed `string` for the `myString` variable.

=> `myContract.reverseStrArg('HelloWorld')` will return reversed `string` for the given argument.

I did single arithmatic operation (subtraction) inside the for loop.

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;

contract myContract {
    string myString;

    function setStr(string memory _str) public
    {
        myString = _str;
    }

    function reverseStrMain() public view returns (string memory)
    {
        return reverseStr(myString);
    }

    function reverseStrArg(string memory strIn) public view returns (string memory)
    {
        return reverseStr(strIn);
    }

    function reverseStr(string memory strIn) internal pure returns (string memory)
    {
        bytes memory _myString = bytes(strIn);
        uint256 count = _myString.length;
        uint256 end   = count - 1;
        bytes memory reveresedStr = new bytes(count);

        for (uint256 begin = 0; begin < count; begin++)
            reveresedStr[begin] = _myString[end--];

        return string(reveresedStr);
    }

}
```